# Why are not ROWIDs updated after VACUUM when using python sqlite3 module?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm working on an app that employs the python sqlite3 module. My database makes use of the implicit ROWID column provided by sqlite3. I expected that the ROWIDs be reordered after I delete some rows and vacuum the database. Because in the sqlite3 official document:

> The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that
>   do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

My pysqlite version is `2.6.0` and the sqlite version is `3.5.9`. Can anybody tell me why it is not working? Anything I should take care when using vacuum?

**P.S.** I have a standalone sqlite installed whose version is `3.3.6`. I tested the vacuum statement in it, and the ROWIDs got updated. So could the culprit be the version? Or could it be a bug of pysqlite?

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions!

Comment: It only says "may change".

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks for your reply. So by 'may', does it mean the actual implementation vary with version? Or even for the same version, the behavior is unpredictable?

Comment: @JanneKarila I have tested it with the latest sqlite(3.7.17). The ROWIDs are not updated either. So I think my first assumption makes sense. If that is the case, do you know if there is any way to force the ROWIDs to be updated so that they are always continuous? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is version dependent.

If you want a guaranteed reordering, you have to copy all records into a new table yourself.
(This works with both implicit and explicit ROWIDs.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That really helps! BTW, is the reordered version of VACUUM actually implemented this way?

Comment: `VACUUM` creates a new database file and copies all data over.